# Is it possible to do embedding-to-embedding translation using a convolutional or fully-connected Autoencoder?

Tags: pytorch, neural-network, autoencoder

I have an Autoencoder network A in PyTorch that embeds a sentence into a fixed-size embedding space (e.g. 512 dimensions), then squashes all the information into a 256 bottleneck layer and then reconstructs the entire sentence off of that layer. The sentences are not very long (max length of 50 tokens) and so the AE does a perfect job replicating the original sentence. I would now like to extract the 256 dimensional embeddings from network A and use them as input to another network B, which will translate them into the embedding of a target sentence. In other words, given embedding x of a source sentence I want network B to output embedding y of a target sentence.

I tried two approaches: In the first one I extracted the embeddings using the AE and then I tried to translate them to the target embeddings with a simple Fully Connected network and the MSELoss. That didn't work, the loss would not decrease.

For the second approach I tried using a VAE, where the idea is to perform the reparametrization trick. Again, network A produces the embeddings, network B should produce embeddings that are similar to the ones fed to it. That also produces very high loss that is not decreasing.

Why is this idea not working? Why can the model not learn to do embedding-to-embedding translation? I did not expect it to be that easy, but I do not understand why it does not work either. Why does it work for images but not text? I am interested in the intuition behind it. Would my idea work if I used another architecture for network A, e.g. a Transformer network or an RNN? Here is a code example for network A that extracts the embedding:

```py
class CNNEncode(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # INFO

        # LAYERS
        self.embed = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, n_embed*4)
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv1d(n_embed*4, max_l, 3, stride=3, padding=1, dilation = 2)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv1d(max_l, n_embed*1, 3, stride=3, padding=1, dilation = 4)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(512, 256)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(256, 64*max_l)
        self.ln = nn.LayerNorm(256)
        self.ln2 = nn.LayerNorm(64, 1)
        self.out = nn.Linear(64, vocab_size)



        
    def forward(self, x):
        emb = self.embed(x)
        B,T,C = emb.shape
        emb = emb.view(B, C, T)
        logits = self.conv1(emb)
        logits = self.relu(logits)
        #print(logits.shape)
        logits = self.conv2(logits)
        logits = self.relu(logits)
        #print(logits.shape)
        B,T,C = logits.shape
        logits = logits.view(B, -1)
        logits = torch.tanh(logits)
        #print(logits.shape)
        logits = self.fc(logits)
        #logits = torch.tanh(logits)
        logits = self.ln(logits)
        #print(logits)
        logits = self.fc2(logits)
        #logits = torch.tanh(logits)
        #logits = self.ln2(logits)
        logits = self.relu(logits)
        logits = logits.view(B, max_l, 64)
        #print(logits.shape)
        out = self.out(logits)



        return out
```

And here is an example of a VAE that attempts to reconstruct the embeddings from network A (the output from fc layer):

```py
class VariationalAutoEncoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, n_dim=128, h_dim=100, z_dim=64):
        super().__init__()
        #encoder, input is the embedding extracted from network A


        self.img_2hid = nn.Linear(256, h_dim)
        self.hid_2mu = nn.Linear(h_dim, z_dim)
        self.hid_2sigma = nn.Linear(h_dim, z_dim)
        
        #decode
        self.z_2hid = nn.Linear(z_dim, h_dim)
        self.hid_2img = nn.Linear(h_dim, 256)
        
        
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.sig = nn.Sigmoid()
    
    def encode(self, x):

        h = self.relu(self.img_2hid(x))
        h = self.sig(h)
        #print("h", h.shape)
        mu = self.hid_2mu(h)
        sigma = self.hid_2sigma(h)
        return mu, sigma
    
    def decode(self, z):
        h = self.relu(self.z_2hid(z))
        #print("dec h", h.shape)
        return self.sig(self.hid_2img(h))
        
    
    def forward(self, x):
        mu, sigma = self.encode(x)
        epsilon = torch.randn_like(sigma)
        z_parametrized = mu + sigma* epsilon
        x_reconstructed = self.decode(z_parametrized)
        return x_reconstructed, mu, sigma

model = VariationalAutoEncoder(input_dim=max_l, n_dim=128, h_dim=200, z_dim=64).to(device)
opt = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=lr)
print(sum(p.nelement() for p in model.parameters()))
loss_fn = nn.BCELoss(reduction = "sum")
```